# Dynamic Div with a table asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to add a **table** and rows to a dynamically created `div` element?

```
Dim divTable As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
    divTable.ID = "divTable"
    divTable.Attributes("class") = "printtable"
    divTable.InnerHtml = "<asp:Table ID=""table1"" CellPadding=""1"" runat=""server"">  </asp:Table>"
    divPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(divTable)
```

I need to add dynamic rows to `table1` but obviously whenever i try to access `table1` from the code file it says `'table1' not declared`.

Help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a `Panel`(which is rendered as a `div`) to the `PlaceHolder` or use just a `Panel` alone as container? You have to add the `Table` as server-control instance to that panel.

```
Dim divTable As New Panel()
divTable.ID = "divTable"
divTable.CssClass = "printtable"
divPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(divTable) ' the placeholder is redundant with a panel '
Dim table As New Table()
table.ID = "table1"
table.CellPadding = 1
divTable.Controls.Add(table)
```

You can find and access this table via `FindControl`:

```
Dim divTable As Panel = DirectCast(divPlaceHolder.Controls(0), Panel)
Dim table As Table = DirectCast(divTable.Controls(0), Table)
```

Remember that you need to recreate all dynamically created controls on every postback  with  the same ID's as before in `Page_Load` at the latest.

Comment: but how can i access table1 i have to add dynamic rows to it, like tr.Cells.Add(tc) table1.Rows.Add(tr)

Answer (score 0):

It won't as you are appending a `String` to your dynamically created div`.

Your apprach isn't correct try it this way.

```
Table table1= new Table();
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.Text = "blah blah blah";
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your existing DIV need to have runat=server property. Then you are able call it from codebehind

```
<div id="divRunServer" runat="server"></div>
```

In codebehind call that control and use Table web ui control to create dynamic html element.

```
//prepare dynamic table
        Table Table1 = new Table();

        int numrows = 3;
        int numcells = 2;
        for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
        {          
            TableRow r = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < numcells; i++) {
                TableCell c = new TableCell();
                c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("row " 
                    + j.ToString() + ", cell " + i.ToString()));
                r.Cells.Add(c);
            }
            Table1.Rows.Add(r);
        }

//add to div

       divRunServer.Controls.Add(Table1)
```

[Referred from](http://forums.asp.net/t/1813007.aspx)